# Swapping contents and positions of divs by clicking

Tags: jquery, click, swap

I've seen in the current Gatorade site where they have four versions of the same product, the only difference are the flavours. In the look and feel you can see four products where one of them is outstanding regards of the others.

IOW, you have four products, three with small sizes and the fourth that is bigger that the others. When user click one of these three small product, automatically the product was clicked is replaced for the main product, and they swap the places and sizes between them.

You can take a look about I want [here](http://www.gatorade.com/products/g-series/sports-fuel-drink).

Is very complex to achieve this?
I just know HTML, CSS and a little of Jquery.

**EDIT:**
The code that I think for this functionality should below:

```html
<ul class="products">
    <li><a href="#" class="red">red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="blue">blue</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="green">green</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="featured">
    <li><a href="#" class="yellow">yellow</a></li>
</ul>
```

If the user clicks on one of three products of the  with class="products", this should swap with the product inside into the  with class="featured". Let's suppose, the user clicks the blue product, so the HTML would be next:

```html
<ul class="products">
    <li><a href="#" class="red">red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="yellow">yellow</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="green">green</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="featured">
    <li><a href="#" class="blue">blue</a></li>
</ul>
```

Besides, if it's possible add a fade animation, would be great.
This is my first attempt in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfdesign/7qg4pfgy/1/), but I haven't done any JS script yet.

Comment: Can include `html` , `css` , `js` tried at Question ?

Comment: It is just simple image switching and fairly easy to achieve with HTML, CSS and JS/Jquery. Please share your code so I can help further.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it. I am sure must be a better solution, but the mine it's:

**HTML**

```
<p>Choose one of the products</p>
<ul class="products">
    <li><a href="#" class="red">red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="blue">blue</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="green">green</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<!--/ here would display the picked product as highlighted and would swap with the current one. -->
<ul class="featured">
    <li><a href="#" class="yellow">yellow</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
ul.products li {
    float:left;
    margin:0 2px 0;
}
ul.products li a {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
}

a.red, a.blue, a.green, a.yellow {
    background:red;
    display:block;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
a.blue {
    background:blue;
}
a.green {
    background:green;
}
a.yellow {
    background:yellow;
}

ul.featured > li > a {
    width:135px !important;
    height:135px !important;
    cursor: default;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
 $("ul.products li").click(function () {
     var strDiv1Cont = $(this).html();
     var strDiv2Cont = $("ul.featured li").html();
     $(this).html(strDiv2Cont);
     $("ul.featured li").hide().html(strDiv1Cont).fadeIn(1500);
 });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfdesign/ebeqkak7/).